# WebGL - display a sphere on a plane

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, webgl, shader, vertex-shader

I would like to show an image like it was on a sphere - but on a plane. 
An example of this operation, would be the Mercatore projection, the map of the earth "unrolled" from the planet.
To better explain myself, having a squared texture on a sphere - not on the WHOLE sphere, but on a part of it only - I would like to show on a plane the result of seeing this texture on the sphere.
I found this, already:
[How do I 'wrap' a plane over a sphere with three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23405683/how-do-i-wrap-a-plane-over-a-sphere-with-three-js)

But I would like to do it with shaders, because it might the most efficient, but probably also the most difficult. I have problems finding the right formula for it. There exists any mathematical framework for it?

Comment: I don't quite get it. What data do you have in what form and what do you want to produce? Can you explain this with an image?

Comment: Hi @NicoSchertler, edited the question!

Comment: So what data do you have? If you want to do Mercatore projection, there are formulas for that. What do you want to know?

Comment: I have an image, I want to display it like shown on the image on the right, but with WebGL. This image is taken from Hugin software.

Comment: This does only make sense if you use two different projections (one forward and one backward). Anyway, just look up the formulas of the projections you want to use.

Comment: Do you know where I can get such information? projections like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify what projection you really want. There are many approaches for curved surfaces (not just for spheres). Your problem is the inverse of such transform so first the direct projection (plane -> sphere surface). I use these two (both are used for specific purposes):

[image: projections]

1. **distances from middle of area on the sphere match the distances on the plane**

   this is used to correct textures on curved surfaces for example Ornament dekors on glasses etc...
2. **perpendicular distances to the view axis on the sphere match the distances on the plane**

   so if you are looking from the view axis you see the same image on the sphere and on the plane just set the coordinate system so `Z` axis is the viewing direction and `x,y` axises are corresponding to your 2D plane axises. Then just compute z-coordinate to match sphere surface

**I think you want the first option**

so compute middle point `(x0,y0)` as center of bounding box or for evenly spaced point average point. Compute `ang` for each point and coordinate (from middle point) via `atan2` **in radians !!!**

Then compute `dx,dy` and compute 2D coordinates as `(x,y)=(x0+dx,y0+dy)`

Here example of the result (I use this for any kind of curvature):

[image: example]

**[Notes]**

There are also another approaches based on ray casting,and possibly much more ...

**[edit1] C++ example**

Busted small C++ class for you:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <Math.h>
class sphere_projection
    {
public:
    float x0,y0,z0,r0;  // 3D sphere
    float u0,v0;        // mid point of 2D image
    float m;            // scale 2D image
    int   mode;         // which projection type
    sphere_projection()
        {
        x0=0.0; y0=0.0; z0=0.0; r0=1.0;
        u0=0.0; v0=0.0; m=1.0;
        mode=1;
        }
    void uv2xyz(float &x,float &y,float &z,float u,float v)
        {
        if (mode==1)
            {
            float a,b;
            // 2D position scaled around midpoint and converted from arclength to angle
            u=(u-u0)*m/r0;
            v=(v-v0)*m/r0;
            // correct on radius distrotion in both axises
            a=u/cos(v);
            b=v/cos(u);
            // compute the 3D cartesian point on surface
            z=z0+(r0*cos(b)*cos(a));
            x=x0+(r0*cos(b)*sin(a));
            y=y0+(r0*sin(b));
            }
        if (mode==2)
            {
            // 2D position scaled around midpoint
            x=(u-u0)*m;
            y=(v-v0)*m;
            // compute the 3D cartesian point on surface
            x=x0+x;
            y=y0+y;
            z=z0+sqrt(r0*r0-x*x-y*y);
            }
        }
    void uv2xy (float &x,float &y,         float u,float v)
        {
        if (mode==1)
            {
            float a,b,z;
            // 2D position scaled around midpoint and converted from arclength to angle
            a=(u-u0)*m/r0;
            b=(v-v0)*m/r0;
            // correct on radius distrotion in both axises and convert back to 2D position
            x=u0+(a*r0/(m*cos(b)));
            y=v0+(b*r0/(m*cos(a)));
            }
        if (mode==2)
            {
            float z;
            // 2D position scaled around midpoint + Z axis
            x=(u-u0)*m;
            y=(v-v0)*m;
            z=sqrt(r0*r0-x*x-y*y);
            // compute arclengths and convert back to 2D position
            x=u0+(r0*atan2(x,z)/m);
            y=v0+(r0*atan2(y,z)/m);
            }
        }
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how to use this (render in OpenGL):

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0.0,+2.5,-20.0);

static float ang=0.0; ang+=2.5;
float x,y,z,u,v,d=0.2;
sphere_projection sp;
sp.x0=0.0;
sp.y0=0.0;
sp.z0=0.0;
sp.r0=1.5;
sp.u0=0.0;
sp.v0=0.0;
sp.m =0.5;


for (sp.mode=1;sp.mode<=2;sp.mode++)
    {
    // original 2D grid
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(-5.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    for (u=d-1.0;u<=1.0;u+=d)
     for (v=d-1.0;v<=1.0;v+=d)
        {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        glVertex3f(u-d,v-d,0.0);
        glVertex3f(u-d,v  ,0.0);
        glVertex3f(u  ,v  ,0.0);
        glVertex3f(u  ,v-d,0.0);
        glEnd();
        }
    // sphere mapped corrected
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(+5.0,0.0,0.0);
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef(ang,0.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    for (u=d-1.0;u<=1.0;u+=d)
     for (v=d-1.0;v<=1.0;v+=d)
        {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        sp.uv2xyz(x,y,z,u-d,v-d); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        sp.uv2xyz(x,y,z,u-d,v  ); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        sp.uv2xyz(x,y,z,u  ,v  ); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        sp.uv2xyz(x,y,z,u  ,v-d); glVertex3f(x,y,z);
        glEnd();
        }
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPopMatrix();

    // sphere mapped corrected
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslatef(+5.0,0.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    for (u=d-1.0;u<=1.0;u+=d)
     for (v=d-1.0;v<=1.0;v+=d)
        {
        glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
        sp.uv2xy(x,y,u-d,v-d); glVertex3f(x,y,0.0);
        sp.uv2xy(x,y,u-d,v  ); glVertex3f(x,y,0.0);
        sp.uv2xy(x,y,u  ,v  ); glVertex3f(x,y,0.0);
        sp.uv2xy(x,y,u  ,v-d); glVertex3f(x,y,0.0);
        glEnd();
        }

    glTranslatef(-5.0,-5.0,0.0);
    }

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
SwapBuffers(hdc);
```

This is the result:

[image: example]

- `sp.uv2xy` converts 2D (u,v) image coordinate to projection corrected 2D (x,y) coordinate (image)
- `sp.uv2xyz` converts 2D (u,v) image coordinate to projection corrected 3D (x,y,x) coordinate (sphere surface where x,y axises corresponds with screen x,y axises)
- `sp.mode` {1,2} selects whitch type of projection you want to use
- `sp.u0,v0,m` selects the projection image mid point and scale
- `sp.x0,y0,z0,r0` defines the sphere on which you are projecting

**[edit2] Sphere EquirectangularProjection**

There is no correction needed for this one 2D `u,v` coordinate is directly converted to spherical angles `a=long,b=lat` so for `u,v` in range `<0,+1>`:

```
a=x*2.0*M_PI; b=(y-0.5)*M_PI;
```

Then the 3D coordinate is just spherical transformation:

```
x=x0+(r0*cos(b)*cos(a));
y=y0+(r0*cos(b)*sin(a));
z=z0+(r0*sin(b));
```

[image: Sphere_EquirectangularProjection]

if you want the reverse transform google spherical coordinate system

Comment: Thank You. But actually, the last two images are not very clear to me.. I would like to project 1) the image on a sphere (like shown to the left on the image in the question) and then from there, 2) project the image in equirectangular projection on the plane (as shown to the right).
I think, from your code, that the 2) option does the first part, though doesn't enlarge the bottom and the top of the image, but only restricts the lateral sides at the center

Comment: @Novalink it is an example of the equal distances from middle point. The transparency is a bit messed up  basically source is square grid image (2D vector format)  then the corrections are applied on it and the image shows the corrected image on plane (on the right) and the same image mapped on curved cylindrical surface (on the left). Yes it is applied on x axis only because that was the purpose of that particular program but you can apply this on booth axises at the same time (this was just easy to show image as I got it already working)

Comment: I think there is some trouble with your formula in 2), it seems to project the image on a hyperboloid, and not on a sphere..

Comment: In fact if I square the radius in the root and add a minus in front of the y it gets projected on a sphere..

Comment: @Novalink sorry was pretty busy last few days ,... added [edit1] to my answer with some example C++ code for sphere projection corrections

Comment: My god, thank you very much, actually in the meanwhile I was going to finish but with some problems, maybe your code will work.. thanks!

Comment: Does this work on the whole globe? It goes on well in the frontal area, but it has some problems in the pole. I'm using the function uv2xy  in mode 2, and it depicts the image on the center well, a bit distorted but ok. Just, when I move it up to the north pole or to the south of the sphere it starts to "break" somehow. Could we have a chat so that I show you?

Comment: Btw, I've just checked better, the projection you use there is stereographic, and I need equirectangular..

Comment: @Novalink none of the spherical projection corrections work on the whole globe (there is just not enough area because sphere is the minimal surface object). You need to select reference point in image `(u0,v0)` and on the sphere surface `(0.0,0.0)` if you need different point then rewrite it to `(a0,b0)`. The best accuracy is near these points, the further away the less precision. If you need something that works on full globe then you need to specify the kind of projection better (but it would be distortion of some sorts not correction)

Comment: Thanks. "Equirectangular" it's a cylindrical projection, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquirectangularProjection.html
and it's completely different from stereographic projection. This second has a completely different approach, and you can see it from the kind of distortion. If you see the image above, you get the difference. The Equirectangular projection has a regular grid, while Stereographic projection has this kind of grid: http://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/stereographic/images/Image_24.jpg

Comment: @Novalink added  `Equirectangular` example

Comment: I am new to webGL, to make answer easier to understand can you please create JSfiddle?

Comment: @m no as I do not code in JS ...